# Android refreshing Seekbar progress and playback duration in audio player causing lags in audio playback

Tags: android, audio

I am making an audio player app, I want to be able to refresh a seekbar that shows current playback position and a textview that shows the time. I am able to do that but there is a problem. Every second when the seekbar and textview update, there is a small lag in audio. It's like it pauses for a short duration every second when the views update.

Here is my updater class

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
class refreshSeekBar extends Thread{

private Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

@Override
public void run() {
    startRefreshingSeekBar();
}

private void startRefreshingSeekBar(){
    Global.scheduledFuture = Global.scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long S = Global.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            S = S/1000;
            long M = S/60;
            S = S%60;
            String SS = ""+S;
            String MM = ""+M;
            if((S/10)<1){
                SS = "0"+SS;
            }
            if((M/10)<1){
                MM = "0"+MM;
            }
            final String MMM = MM;
            final String SSS = SS;
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Global.seekBar.setProgress(Global.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    Global.textCurrentDuration.setText(MMM+":"+SSS);
                }
            });
        }
    },0,1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I had not used the boolean fromUser in the seekbar's OnSeekBarChangeListener to prevent it being called when progress was set programmatically. Whenever the progress was updating, it was seeking the mediaPlayer and hence the lags.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my app and it runs without any lags, my code converts milliseconds to minutes and seconds without using if statements.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
            currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            total = mPlayer.getDuration();

            while (mPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
                seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // This code will always run on the UI thread, therefore is safe to modify UI elements.
                        String currTime = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(currentPosition),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(currentPosition) -
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(currentPosition))
                        );
                        currentPos.setText(currTime);

                    }
                });
            }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the conversion of time unit without the if condition